# ¿Cómo resolver este problema al conectar con MySQL por JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

Necesito que me ayuden por que me estoy volviendo loco. Estoy haciendo un programa la cual quiero traer todos los datos de mi tabla de mysql y convertirlos a objeto.. Pero segun el debug que realice tengo un ***NullPointerException***.

PD: La conexión esta correctamente hecha, a traves de los servicios .. pero no lo puedo lograr conectar a traves de codigo. ahi va mis clases..

```
@WebServlet("/ServletControlador")
public class ServletControlador extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest reque, HttpServletResponse respo) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Cliente> listaClientes = new conecction.ConexionDaoJDBC().listar();

        reque.setAttribute("lista", listaClientes);
        reque.getRequestDispatcher("cliente.jsp").forward(reque, respo);

    }
}
```

En esta clase es donde llamo al metodo listar, donde va a pegar primero a la clase conexion, a buscar la conexion a mysql y luego hace un select y lo va guardando en una lista.

```
    public class ConexionDaoJDBC {

    private static final String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM control_clientes.cliente";

    private static final String SQL_SELECT_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idcliente =?";

    private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO clientes(nombre, apellido, email, saldo, telefono) "
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?)";

    private static final String SQL_UPDATE = "UPDATE clientes "
            + "SET nombre =?, apellido =?, email =?, saldo =?, telefono =? WHERE id_cliente =?";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE idcliente =?";

    public List<Cliente> listar() {

        List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null; //RECUPERA INFORMACION

        try {
            conn = Conexion.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                int idcliente = rs.getInt("idcliente");
                String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
                String apellido = rs.getString("apellido");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                double saldo = rs.getDouble("saldo");
                String telefono = rs.getString("telefono");

                Cliente c = new Cliente(idcliente, nombre, apellido, email, saldo, telefono);
                listaClientes.add(c);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(System.in);
        } finally {
            Conexion.close(conn);
            Conexion.close(stmt);
            Conexion.main(rs);
        }
        return listaClientes;
    }
```

El metodo para listar todos los registros, como dije, busca primero la conexion y lo guarda como objeto.

```
    public class Conexion {

    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/control_clientes?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";
    private static final String JDBC_USER = "root";
    private static final String JDBC_PASS = "admin";

    public static BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUrl(JDBC_URL);
        ds.setUsername(JDBC_USER);
        ds.setPassword(JDBC_PASS);
        ds.setInitialSize(50); //ESTABLECEMOS CUANTAS CONEXIONES QUEREMOS
        return ds;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return getDataSource().getConnection();
    }

    public static void main(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }

    public static void close(PreparedStatement ps) {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection conn) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo la clase conexion. Dejo mi tabla mysql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, debe ser una boludez. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer te falta regitrar la clase del JDBC de mysql:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {

private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/control_clientes?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";
private static final String JDBC_USER = "root";
private static final String JDBC_PASS = "admin";

public static BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Driver de mysql
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setUrl(JDBC_URL);
    ds.setUsername(JDBC_USER);
    ds.setPassword(JDBC_PASS);
    ds.setInitialSize(50); //ESTABLECEMOS CUANTAS CONEXIONES QUEREMOS
    return ds;
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return getDataSource().getConnection();
}

public static void main(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}

public static void close(PreparedStatement ps) {
    try {
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}

public static void close(Connection conn) {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```